# Turn data type into a map

Tags: haskell, recursion, dictionary, algebraic-data-types

I want to turn my data type, Exp, into a map where the function names (Add, Subtract, etc) are the keys and the values are the number of times they occurred in an expression.  Here is my data declaration:

```
data Exp = Number     Int
         | Add        Exp Exp
         | Subtract   Exp Exp
         | Multiply   Exp Exp
         | Divide     Exp Exp
  deriving Show
```

I can do this problem with a BST but I can't seem to accomplish this task with a different data type.  Here is my BST solution if it helps:

```
import Data.Map 

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
leaf x = Node x Empty Empty

foldt :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldt f a Empty = a
foldt f a (Node x xl xr) = f x ar 
                           where al = foldt f a xl
                                 ar = foldt f al xr

insert' :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int 
insert' a = insertWith (+) a 1 

toMap :: Ord a => Tree a -> Map a Int
toMap = foldt insert' empty
```

It seems like it should be simple after doing the above program but I don't even know where to start.  Note:  I want to use as much recursion as possible.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tree function worked with trees that contained `a` to make values of type `b`, but your `Exp` data type doesn't contain anything except expressions to combine (or count). Let's make a second data type that we can count occurences of. It'd better be `Ord`, so we need `Eq`, and `Show`'ll be good for output:

```
data Term = NumberTerm | AddTerm | SubtractTerm | MultiplyTerm | DivideTerm
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Each of those represents a term of the `Exp` type.

I've renamed your `insert'` to `inc`:

```
inc :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int 
inc a = insertWith (+) a 1
```

---

No we're ready to count:

```
countExp :: Exp -> Map Term Int
```

A `Number` has just one term (no subterms), so we'll start with `empty` and increment the number of `NumberTerm`s:

```
countExp (Number _) = inc NumberTerm empty
```

`Add` terms are more complicated. Each expression has its own count, so we use `countExp` recursively on each subterm, then we `unionWith (+)` to sum the counts. After that, we `inc AddTerm` to include the current `Add` term in the totals.

```
countExp (Add e1 e2) = inc AddTerm $ unionWith (+) (countExp e1) (countExp e2)
```

We can do almost exactly the same for `Subtract`:

```
countExp (Subtract e1 e2) = inc SubtractTerm $ unionWith (+) (countExp e1) (countExp e2)
```

You get the idea now I hope so you can finish off.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I was able to get it working and now I'm just breaking it down and trying to understand what is happening.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, which is a slight variation on AndrewC's answer. Rather than creating a separate data type representing the constructors of your `Exp` type as numbers, you could instead represent expressions as a free monad over a simpler base type. For example, if the base type is

```
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Map

data ExpT a = Number a
            | Add a a
            | Subtract a a
            | Multiply a a
            | Divide a a
            deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

then your expressions can be defined as the free monad over `ExpT`, with `Int` as the root type

```
type Exp = Free ExpT Int
```

Now you write `inc` as in AndrewC's post

```
inc :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int
inc a = insertWith (+) a 1
```

and the `countExp` function is again very similar

```
countExp :: Exp -> Map (ExpT ()) Int
countExp (Free (Number _)) = inc (Number ()) empty
countExp (Free (Add a b))  = inc (Add () ()) $ unionWith (+) (countExp a) (countExp b)
```

et cetera. You'll probably want to define some convenience functions for creating expressions

```
number :: Int -> Exp

number n = Free (Number (Pure n))
add a b  = Free (Add a b)
sub a b  = Free (Subtract a b)
mul a b  = Free (Multiply a b)
divide a b = Free (Divide a b)
```

and the final result is

```
>>> countExp (add (number 1) (number 2))
fromList [(Number (),2),(Add () (),1)]
```

Comment: Looking at it again, you don't actually need `Free` -- you could use `Fix` which would be just as good.